# Postscript mutilates font

Tags: pdf, fonts, printing, libreoffice, postscript

I am using the DejaVu Serif font in LibreOffice 7.5.4.2. An exported PDF looks like this:

> [image: exported PDF, looks good]

However, when I print that PDF (or export it into PostScript), it transforms to:

> [image: exported into PostScript, glitches visible]

The italic "M" is the most obvious one, but not only it. "N" looks different too, some digits etc. There are quite a few differences if you look closely.

If I instead do PDF→SVG→PDF→PS then the result is okay.

What are those weird glitches when doing straight PDF→PS?

UPDATE:

> You don't say **how** you are turning the PDF into PostScript

I am using Evince/Document Viewer for GNOME on Linux as on the screenshot below. But, exactly the same distortions occur when I actually print out the PDF file from a Mac machine, so they have nothing to do with the particular PDF→PS way I am using.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the problem with M italic? Please describe the exact problem(s)

Comment: @RomeoNinov The italic "M" is the most obvious one, but not only it. "N" looks different too, some digits etc. There are quite a few differences if you look closely.

Comment: About M for me looks like bug in the PS code which define the letter. Try to get the font from different source and install it again. Also check the resolution you use to print it.

Comment: @RomeoNinov If it is a bug in the font, why would it look okay in the PDF on screen? Also, when I print to *.ps file there is no resolution option. It's vector after all, isn't it?

Comment: I have no explanation, maybe it depend of the PS RIP which is in charge for screen, print, file.

Comment: I'd guess (and guessing is all I can do without seeing the files) that the font is a TrueType font which is being converted to a type 1 (or 3) PS font and having a problem with the hinting program, leading to points being mispositioned. By going to SVG you are either converting the font to vectors or to bitmap image, which is obviously working better. You don't say **how** you are turning the PDF into PostScript, so there's not a lot more that can be said. Actually, looking at the 7th line of text, maybe whatever you are using to create the PostScript is rendering the glyphs to bitmaps, badly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring with the Linux version of LibreOffice.

I have now installed it on a Mac, opened the same *.odt file, exported to PDF and then directly to PS. And it all looks just nice.

There must be something wrong either with the font itself on the Linux distribution of LibreOffice, or with how the latter renders PDFs.

Comment: Or maybe with some of the PS RIPs involved in to the process :(

Comment: It is possible that Evince and CUPS (which does the printing) are both using Ghostscript to do the PDF to PostScript conversion, and it is possible you are running different versions of Ghostscript on the two systems. You could check that. You could also use Ghostscript directly to create a PostScript program from the PDF file. Also, you don't say how you are viewing the PostScript, as Romeo Ninov says, that could also be a difference.

Comment: I think I recall CUPS likes to mangle fonts, but it may be the print driver in use: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042347/pdf-font-mangling-on-printing-mixed-results

Comment: @KenS The mangling seems to be vested in the PDF itself as it occurs no matter what platform the PDF is printed from.

Comment: Including Windows ? The reason I ask about Windows is that the Mac, like Linux uses CUPS to do it's printing and so may well be using Ghostscript 'under the hood'. But really it isn't important, as you have a solution.

Comment: @KenS Looks like you're right, it's only Linux and Mac. I just "printed" it to an *.xps file on Windows 7 and that looks fine without issues.